# How can i validate a SOAP message with a WSDL file?

Tags: c#, parameters, wsdl, schema, validation

when we receive a SOAP message,
then we Resolve it,
then we have a TEXT like:

```
<soap:Envelope>
        <soap:Body>
                <GetDNS>
                  <xx>1</xx>
                </GetDNS>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

how can i validate the para: xx .
 to check it's value is accord to the WSDL of the web service

Comment: Your question may not have come out formatted the way you were hoping....  In general, whatever framework you're using for your SOAP handling will automatically validate messages.  Can you give us a little more detail about what your environment looks like?

Comment: i catch the httpwebrequest in the global
so i catch the xml message body from the httpcontext
i would not to use the validation if the .net framework
i want check the request by myself
so i will write a function to deal with the validation to the xml message to the WSDL schema file

Comment: the work i need to do is below:
1.receive a http message (xml)
2.validate it with the SOAP NameSpace
3.validate it to my WSDL to check the para is good for the WSDL
4.validate the body path is fit to my XSDs defined by myself